# Jira Soap Api Add Watchers

Tags: c#, soap, jira

I have used Jira api and  C#.

Create is working fine. But I want to add extra watchers problem.

```
    customField[1] = new RemoteCustomFieldValue();
    var watcher = new string[1];
    watcher[0] = mailItem.Cc[0];
    customField[1].values = watcher;
    customField[1].customfieldId = "customfield_10280";

    newIssue.customFieldValues = customField;
```

No error, but watchers are not added.

Help please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
The user needs to be added as defined followers. Firstly checked users. If is not defined, I add users.

```
JiraService.createUser(_auth, username.ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")), password, fullname, email);
```